# how to do nCr in python? with example

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list of actions that uses a group of people (8 people),

```
actions = [
    ('take one soldier off duty', n, 200),
    ('take two soldiers off duty', nC2, 200)
    ('take three soldiers off duty', nC3, 200)
    ('replace soldier', n, 200)
]
```

I know I can physically write out all the different actions by hand. e.g

```
actions = [
    ('take one soldier off duty', 0, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 1, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 2, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 3, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 4, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 5, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 6, 200),
    ('take one soldier off duty', 7, 200),
]
```

I am just trying to do it more efficiently/look nicer so its not just a massive list of the same written bar one number- any help would be great!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the meaning of `nC2`?

Comment: take a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations): `itertools.combinations(range(200), r)` where `r` is the number of soldiers taken off duty

Comment: @Tranbi I have done this    'import itertools
itertools.combinations(range(8), 2)'     and get this as the result <itertools.combinations at 0x102ef7290>

Comment: What do you want to do with? You can iterate through it, convert it to list...

Answer (score 0):

Use `combinations` function from `itertools` module. Produce a combination, then convert the result in list and print.

Complete code:

```
from itertools import combinations
r =int(input())
comb = combinations(range(1, 200), r)
comb = list(comb)
# print(*comb)
for c in comb:
  print(c)
```